# Were Pandaria, Broken Isles, Northrend, Kul'Tiras and Zandalar also affected by the Cataclysm?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was wondering if Pandaria, Broken Isles, Northrend, Kul'Tiras and Zandalar were also affected by the cataclysm.

When questing through these places, I did not notice one of the NPCs say something about strange things happening over the last years, the earth shaking or anything.

So my question would be:

- Were these places affected by the cataclysm?
- if not, why not?

Comment: I think I've heard NPCs talk about the cataclysm in Pandaria. No clue about the other regions though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Zandalar**: Yes, definitely

> Zandalar has been severely crippled by the Cataclysm, causing King Rastakhan's palace to list to one side, the spine of the land to split in two, a fissure to open in the floor of the forum, and the region of the island called Nazmir as well as other areas of the island began sinking beneath the waves.
>
> But though Zandalar was indeed damaged, it did not sink as Zul predicted. While Zul and the Golden Fleet left Zandalar, those that stayed behind endured and rebuilt.

---

**Kul Tiras**: Affected, but apparently not damaged

> Kul Tiras, the island nation, will not be visible at the start of
> Cataclysm – something about tectonic plates shifting it out to sea....

---

**Broken Isles**: unlikely

I have found no written evidence about anything Cataclysm related. The Broken Isles are a lot older than the Cataclysm, but there is no mention about any changes or destruction in their history.

---

**Pandaria**: Thrall found it (first?) because of the Cataclysm, but no apparent damage

> It was shrouded by magic mists, leaving the continent protected from the outside.

and

> "His essence raced headlong through the leagues and leagues of earth that unfurled around him. He moved through the sun-baked soil of Durotar and then to the muddy banks of the Swamp of Sorrows. All the lands, no matter how remote or distinct, were connected in a way that he had never comprehended.
>
> Apart from the areas he knew, Thrall encountered other places and oddities in Azeroth of which he had been ignorant.
>
> Somewhere in the Great Sea was a mysterious island shrouded in mists..."

---

**Northrend (and Outland)**: No

From an interview:

> Any plans for Outland and Northrend (zones created in the previous two
> expansions)?
>
> We have started to talk about what we need to do because there's
> currently no congruity between the story that we are telling in
> Cataclysm and the one in Outland. It feels a little weird to have the
> whole "Deathwing is back and has destroyed the world" and then you
> walk into Outland and you're like "Hey! There's this guy, Illidan". We
> don't exactly know how we're going to tackle that yet, but we
> definitely want to find a solution.